# Bonjour multifunction not recognized

Tags: mac-osx, printer, bonjour

I'm using 3 different macOS systems. Only 1 of these systems is able to recognize that my multifunction printer is also a scanner. The other 2 only recognize it as a printer.
The printer in question is a 'Samsung M267x 287x Series'. (Which is now part of HP btw)

I've tracked the problem down to how those 3 systems are seeing the printer on the local network. Only one of them sees the 'Bonjour Multifunction' broadcast. The other 2 only 'Bonjour'.
Now I'm afraid if I upgrade Catalina to something higher, I'll lose the ability to my scanner...

The 3 systems:

- macbook pro 2017, running MacOS Catalina (sees 'Bonjour Multifunction')
- macbook pro 2021 - intel based, running MacOS Mojave (sees 'Bonjour' only)
- imac 2021 - M1 based, running MacOS Mojave (sees 'Bonjour' only)

I'm unsure were the problem is actually based. Is this HP's fault? Or MacOS fault? Is there anything I can do? Haven't found printer drivers on the HP site.
Below are the screenshots from both macbooks
[image: Macbook pro 2017 - Catalina]

[image: Macbook pro 2021 - Mojave, intel based]

## Solution

For future reference, here are the steps to solve this problem:
As mentioned in the solution, I forgot to install a separate section of the driver. In the screenshot, you see 3 folders that are part of the driver download package.
You'll need to install the .pkg file in BOTH the `MAC_Printer` (printer only) folder and the `MAC_ICDM` (for the scanner) folder.

[image]

Comment: Did you install scanner drivers? How are connected the MACs and printer/scanner?

Comment: @Romeo, all is connected through a home LAN network, mostly wired. Tried searching for drivers but haven't found any that works. On HP website, the only drivers available are "Samsung Xpress SL-M2675 Laser Multifunction Printer series"> I've tried those, but without success. I suspect the problem is actually about the Bonjour system not able to see the printer actually is a 'multifunction' printer

Comment: BTW this is not the printer: Samsung M267x 287x Series. Check on physical printer the exact model!

Comment: Label on the printer mentions 'Model: Xpress M2675FN`, so I'm assuming I've tried to correct drivers from the HP website..

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is the only helpful clue I found after looking at hundreds of Google results. For future reference, after installing both drivers, I was able to access the scanner from the PrintAndScan system preferences → Open Scanner button, NOT from the "Samsung Easy Printer Manager". As of v3.93 of the driver on  Ventura, I'm able to use all scanner features including cropping, resolution and image correction. So happy to unlock the machine's potential again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2675-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462855/model/16462859) are the drivers for Xpress M2675FN
When install do not forget to activate install also for scan utilities. And select proper version of your OS.

[Here](https://www.samsung-driver.org/2019/01/samsung-xpress-m2675fn-driver-download-for-mac.html) you can find installation procedure and drivers for MacOS on some site.

For scanning usually drivers install TWAIN driver which you can use with any TWAIN capable software.

Comment: Thanks @Romeo, silly me only partly installed the driver. I've added my solution steps to the question